# PowerBI: Read from the Output of a Query

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

Currently,I am using Postgres as my data source to powerbi reports.

My requirement is:

Power BI report must generate a report based on the output of a query which user runs everytime.

For Eg: If User A(webapp user) runs a reports with one Start Date and End Date on a webapp which runs a query to store the output in postgres table.
Now the User B( powerBI user) from the embedded poweribi url he need to fetch and generate the report with the filters which User A has applied.

Basically power bi query for the output of dabase query. Is this acheivable through Power BI??

Comment: I think, it's only about PowerBI queries. One user want's to ask second user to generate query with some filters on top. If so please consider rewriting your question.

Comment: Here User A is on webapp side where he runs the query...so based on the query output User B need to generate reports on PoweBI